# RSS Feed on Wordpress showing code (hypertext) in articles titles

Tags: plugins, functions, widgets

**The Problem:**
My Rss Feed headlines have hypertext showing like `<b>diving</b>`

**Things I have tried:**
I've looked on forums and found plugins meant to solve it. Nothing worked. I have added code in the function file where devs have asked me to in an attempt to fix it. No dice.

**How I configured the feed:**
I create Google alerts. Copy each alert's RSS link and paste it on to RSSmix.com I have also tried two other mixers, including feedburner. I then combine all the feeds in to one and then add the one rss feed to the widget.

Other Things I've tried:

1. Switching themes
2. Praying to the Spaghetti monster
3. Turning it off and on again.
4. Wingardium Leviosa

All have ended in fail. :(

The website where the problem is occuring: foodandtravel.io

Please advise.

If Samwise Gamgee can brave Mount Doom, we can sure as hell fix this RSS Feed. Together. As one.

I call upon yee my smooth brained brethren.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment! But I can't comment (too little reputation points). So stupid...

Anyway...

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is: you collect some external RSS feeds from the web, and want to display it on your wordpress site? Correct?

Do you use any PHP to display the contents of the feeds? Or is this all done by some plugin? Because my first reflex was: use `<?php strip_tags(); ?>`

If not, I guess you'll have to take it up with your plugin - or its developers.